# Recommended machine learning algorithms for a 10-class image classification problem with only 1900 samples

Tags: python, image-processing, machine-learning, classification

I am trying to determine the right approach to take for an image classification problem which involves 10 classes and only 1900 samples. The images (1288 x 964 resolution) are of industrial parts where each part is represented by one of the 10 classes; the image classes essentially differ in terms of a serial number that is present in the image as well as other subtle features. I've considered using a CNN but am wondering if this may not be recommended due to the size of the data set, i.e. is the data set too small for this? Otherwise I've considered using either the KNN or SVM algorithms which I thought may work better due to less data but am in need of some expert guidance. Thank you.

Comment: Even though you have less training dataset, the feature set is quite rich, (1288 x 964 pixel intensity values). I believe, that comparinig results from multiple algorithms on multiple evaultion metrics will be the best way for you to determine the most effecient algorithm. It's not always that a single algorithm will work fine. Comparative analysis will be a good approach, i believe.

Comment: Without knowing a lot more of the classifications and the same dataset, this question isn't really answerable. How distinct are the classes? How clean are your expected images? What's the impact of incorrect classification? Will there be someone/something intervening to correct misclassified items?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a pretrained feature extractor (f.e. inceptionV3 which is standard in keras). Because it has been trained on other data, only the last layer should be retrained to your specific needs and 100ish images per class should be enough to do that

Comment: Excellent thanks very much, so would you recommend employing this approach with a CNN rather than using a more classic ML algorithm (f.e. kNN)?

Comment: Yes, I would start with the inceptionV3 CNN